# Automatically focusing in the search text box on page load for an ecommerce site

Tags: user-behavior

[This article](http://uxmag.com/articles/designing-search-entering-the-query) (targeted for search sites) says:

> All three sites (google, yahoo and ask) assist the user by placing the cursor within the
>   search box upon page load and allowing the user to press the Enter or
>   Return key to submit the query. In addition, they each reserve a
>   consistent location for the search box, at the top and bottom of the
>   page.

So, can this trick be used on a sites like eBay (they do it), amazon (they don't) or etsy (they don't)?

My reasoning is yes. Because there are 2 kinds of users who come to these eCommerce sites:

1. To search: They know what to search and will quickly navigate to the search box. This "feature" will help them.
2. To browse: Now, for this user auto focusing on the search box won't be a problem since they came to this site to browser and a common user uses a mouse to navigate a site (is that a safe assumption?). So, it won't matter where the focus of your cursor is.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting people who use the keyboard. Auto focusing means you break the backspace key to navigate back a page. When an input control is focused, the backspace key deletes characters (that aren't even there) and no longer functions as a shortcut for the back button.

See also [Drawbacks of auto "focusing" on a web page's text field (JavaScript)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/drawbacks-of-auto-focusing-on-a-web-pages-text-field-javascript)

Comment: But why would some one press a backspace on a homepage? You generally backspace when you are somewhere inside the website.

Comment: And why do you think your home page might be the first page I visit?

Comment: Sorry about that, my assumption was we were talking about the homepage. I do not intend to do that on every page of the site, but just on the homepage, same as google.

Comment: Makes no difference, unless the search box is the only thing on your (home) page. And even then, I would recommend against auto-focus for that because people may land on your home page by accident and auto-focus should really be reserved for forms (form pages) that a user visits with the intention of filling out the form. A home page, like any other page on your site, may be entered "by accident" by inadvertently clicking on a link on some other page/site.

Answer (score 2):

For me it would be the sort of thing I'd A/B test to see if there was any significant difference. Personally I would bet "no".

On your two points both options would hurt me (personally) since I generally navigate around with the keyboard and I normally expect the keyboard focus to be in it's default location. So whether searching or browsing I'm reaching for the tab key straight away - since I "know" that the default location won't be where I need it to be. If somebody moves it then I'm *always* automatically tabbing out of where they want me to be.  Best case I'm confused. Worst case I've just tabbed out of the box where I want to be. Personally it annoys the heck out of me.